# PHP $_POST syntax error

Tags: php

```
<?php `echo $_POST["fname"]; 
 $handler=  fopen('f.txt', 'a')
 $data=$_POST["fname"];
 fwrite($handle,$data);
                    ?>
```

In it i'm not able to pass my $_POST['fname'].(says syntax error)
My aim is to save these in puts in forms to a txt file...

Comment: Even syntax highlighter here on SO can spot the errors...

Comment: hint - start using code highlighting... Even SO's tells what is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you've got a ` in your code and second, you forgot a semicolon on the second line. Use a source code editor with syntax highlighting to spot the syntax errors.

```
<?php
echo $_POST["fname"]; 
$handler=  fopen('f.txt', 'a');
$data=$_POST["fname"];
fwrite($handle,$data);
?>
```